# Аналог typedef в C#

Tags: c#

В C/C++ можно определить псевдоним типа, например,

```
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
```

Как сделать то же самое в C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В C# псевдонимы определяются так:

```
using DWORD = System.UInt64;
```